# How can I echo out an Item's price in Wordpress/ Woocmerce?

Tags: html, sql, woocommerce

lets say I am in the Page section where you put the content in WYSIWYG, my plan is to display one woocomerce item's price using php to pull out the info. I downloaded this Plugin Insert PHP where it allows you to put php code in the WYSIWYG section using a special shortcode. The thing is that I am not an expert on php whatsoever, so how would I even start?

so far I've researched this:

```
<?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>
```

lets say its the item with an SKU: 6-501

how would you do an php to pull the out the price ONLY of that item?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `get_price()` method instead:

```
<?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>
```

Comment: but how or where would you specify which SKU it is? would it be something like

<?php echo $product->get_price('6-501'); ?>

Answer (score 1):

WooCommerce version 2.3 and up has a function `wc_get_product_id_by_sku( $sku )`.

so you could do something like,

```
$sku = '6-501';
$_product_id = wc_get_product_id_by_sku( $sku );
$_product = new WC_Product( $_product_id );
echo $_product->get_price_html();
```

Comment: This is the answer as you need to get the `$product` object. I would advise the OP to wrap this up in a shortcode. Something like `[wc_price sku="6-501"]` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using [Insert PHP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-php/) plugin, Place the following code between `[insert_php]` and `[/insert_php]`:

```
$sku = '6-501';

global $wpdb;
$id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key='_sku' AND meta_value='%s' LIMIT 1", $sku ) );
if ( $id ){
    $product = new WC_Product( $id );
    echo $product->get_price();
}
```

That should work.

Comment: it did, awesome, I am trying to understand the code so I can do it myself.
not sure what this means thoug "$id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key='_sku' AND meta_value='%s' LIMIT 1", $sku ) );
"

Comment: We are getting product id here. `get_var` retrieves a variable from wpdb. `SELECT post_id` says `id` to be that variable. and in `WHERE` condition we are filtering result for particular sku which is saved in post_meta table in wordpress database as  meta_key(_sku) and meta_value(value we are passing). Once we get the id of product, we get product object for that id. That object($product) contains `get_price`. [More Info](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb). Please accept the answer if it worked.